# Is it possible for VS to show more of the C# XML documentation in Intellisense Quick Info pop-ups

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, quickinfo

It seems that VS only shows the contents of the `summary` element, but I would like to see more information like the `detail` for classes and `value` for properties. In fact, even if I click on the Quick Info pop-up to bring up the search dialog, it still only displays the summary, even though there is plenty of space to display much more.

If I am going to add XML documentation to my classes, I would like to see more of it displayed to help me in my development. I don't want to add it solely for the generation of (off-line, i.e., not integrated into VS) documentation.

Is it possible to turn this capability on?

Comment: Same problem here, I would like to see the return value information of methods and properties in the Quick Info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not know if VS has this feature built-in, if you use **[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)**, you can hit **CTRL+Q** on a method or class to see its XML documentation within VS.

[image]